# How to email results of a SQL query in a script task using locks in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I tried using locks in my SSIS script task to write to two variables `emailsubject` and `emailbody` the results of a DB2 query. I also get the total Inserted, Updated and Deleted rows and hold them in several variables.

I'm getting this error:

> Error: 0xC001405C at Script Task: A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variables "User::emailsubject, User::isDataFlowSuccessful" for read/write access. A lock cannot be acquired after 16 attempts. The locks timed out.
>
> Error: 0x2 at Script Task: A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variables "User::emailsubject, User::isDataFlowSuccessful" for read/write access. A lock cannot be acquired after 16 attempts. The locks timed out.
>
> Task failed: Script Task

This is my code:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Variables vars = null;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        int insertedRows1 = 0;
        int insertedRows2 = 0;
        int updatedRows11 = 0;
        int updatedRows12 = 0;
        int updatedRows21 = 0;
        int updatedRows22 = 0;
        int deletedRows = 0;
        string ServerName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::isDataFlowSuccessful");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("$Package::Environment");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("$Package::SqlDatabaseServer");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::InsertedRowCount1");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UpdatedRowCount11");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UpdatedRowCount12");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::InsertedRowCount2");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UpdatedRowCount21");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UpdatedRowCount22");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::DeletedRowCount");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::emailsubject");  // Lock for write access
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::emailbody");     // Lock for write access

            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

            insertedRows1 = (int)vars["User::InsertedRowCount1"].Value;
            insertedRows2 = (int)vars["User::InsertedRowCount2"].Value;
            updatedRows11 = (int)vars["User::UpdatedRowCount11"].Value;
            updatedRows12 = (int)vars["User::UpdatedRowCount12"].Value;
            updatedRows21 = (int)vars["User::UpdatedRowCount21"].Value;
            updatedRows22 = (int)vars["User::UpdatedRowCount22"].Value;
            deletedRows = (int)vars["User::DeletedRowCount"].Value;
            ServerName = (string)vars["$Package::SqlDatabaseServer"].Value;
            bool isDataFlowSuccessful = (bool)vars["User::isDataFlowSuccessful"].Value;
            String Environment = (string)vars["$Package::Environment"].Value;

            int totalInsertedRows = insertedRows1 + insertedRows2;
            int totalUpdatedRows = updatedRows11 + updatedRows12 + updatedRows21 + updatedRows22;
            string message = string.Empty;
            string sql = "SELECT FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE, COUNT(*) FROM LC1U1.Location_Supertbl1 GROUP BY FISCAL_YR, LOC_CODE;";

            string connString = Dts.Connections["TDB1 Connection Manager"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Assuming the result has a single column. Adjust if you have multiple columns.
                        resultBuilder.AppendLine(reader[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            Dts.Connections["TDB1 Connection Manager"].ReleaseConnection(conn);

            // Store the result in the message variable
            message = resultBuilder.ToString();

            if (isDataFlowSuccessful == true)
            {
                Dts.Variables["emailsubject"].Value = "LCGMS_Supertable_Update_Process_LC1P1_" + Environment + ":" + ServerName + " Success on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Dts.Variables["emailbody"].Value = $"In total there was {totalInsertedRows} total Inserted Rows,\t{totalUpdatedRows} total Updated Rows,\t{deletedRows} total Deleted Rows\n\n{message}\nEND";

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["emailsubject"].Value = "LCGMS_Supertable_Update_Process_LC1P1_" + Environment + ":" + ServerName + " Failure on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Dts.Variables["emailbody"].Value = $"In total there was {totalInsertedRows} total Inserted Rows,\t{totalUpdatedRows} total Updated Rows,\t{deletedRows} total Deleted Rows\n\n{message}\nEND";

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
                 vars.Unlock();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Error", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int) ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
```

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong I had these variables in the ReadOnlyVariables and ReadWriteVariables which automatically lock them causing the deadlock in my code.

Comment: You should make your comment into an answer so it can be accepted